# Accumulation points of $A=\left[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n : n=1,2,...\right]$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble finding the accumulation points o set $A=\left[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n : n=1,2,...\right]$. I know that it only has one accumulation point (which is $e$), but I don't know the proof.

If anyone could help me, it would be great.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1+n^{-1})^n=e$?

Comment: @DonThousand: Yes they do. They know that the only accumulation pt is $e$ but cannot prove it.

Comment: Some clarification:  Are you allowed to use $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n$?  Or is that actually part of the proof you need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of an accumulation point, you can see that in any neighbourhood of an accumulation point there is an infinite number of elements of the set. In this case, this means that there are subsequences of $(1+1/n)^n$ converging to any accumulation point of this set. Since the limit exists, all subsequences converge to the same number ($e$) and therefore...

Answer (score 1):

Claim 1: The ordered sequence $a_n = (1+\frac 1n)^n$ is monotonically increasing.

Claim 2: $a_n$ is bounded above.

Now any monotonically increase sequence $A= \{a_n\}$ the following will hold

1. $\sup A$ exists

(all bounded above sets in the reals have a least upper bound) and that

2. $\sup A \not \in A$.

If $\sup A = a$ for some $a\in A$ then $\sup A =a_n$ for some $n$ and $\sup A=a_n < a_{n+1} \in A$, a contradiction.

3. $\sup A$ is a limit point:

Because for any $r> 0$ then $\sup A-r$ is not an upper bound so there is an $a\in A;a\ne \sup A$  so that $\sup A -r < a < \sup A$ so $a \in B_r(\sup A)$.

4. $\sup A$ is the only limit point.

If $x < \sup A$ then there $a\in A; a>x$. And by well-ordering principal there is a least $m$ so that $a_m > x$.  If $x \le a_1$ there are no $b\in A; b < x$ and if we let $r = a_m -x$ then $B_r(x)$ will have no  elements of $A$ (other than $x$ if $x=a+1$).  And if $a_1 < x$ then there will be a maximum $a_k < a$.  Let $r =\min(x-a_k, a_m -x)$ and then $B_r(x)$ will have no elements of $A$ (other than maybe $x$). So $x$ is not a limit point.

And if $x > \sup A$ then let $r = x -\sup A$ and $B_r(x)$ has no points of $A$.

....

So that's that.

$\sup A = \lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n = e$ is the only limit point.

....

I'll leave it to you to prove (or look up.... or take as a given) claims 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

$(1+1/n)^n
\lt e
\lt (1+1/n)^{n+1}
$
so
$0 \lt e-(1+1/n)^n
\lt (1+1/n)^{n+1}-(1+1/n)^n
= (1+1/n)^n((1+1/n)-1)
= (1+1/n)^n/n
\lt e/n
$.